# Not able to publish application on android play store

Tags: android, react-native, inappbrowser

I have developed an application using react native. Unable to upload app on play store because of Query all packages permission, this is happening because of "In App browser reborn" package. Is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Is it possible to you share the issue which you facing while uploading the AAB file on Play Store.

Comment: @Lalitkumar Yeah it is saying that Query all packages permission is enabled, so either need to remove this permission or give a valid reason to use this. It seems like one of the package "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn" is using this. Not sure how to fix this issue

Comment: I think you use react-native-permission package in your code and you allow all permission. Please allow only required permission . in react-native-permission package.